# how to create an alert if the same data has been added using laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks, laravel-8

I made an add user feature, but if I add the same data there will be a problem, I want to limit the duplicate data, how to create a warning if the same data has been added?

**Source Code UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Traits\ImageStorage;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.user.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|max:255',
            'is_admin' => 'required',
        ]);

        $photo = $request->file('image');

        if ($photo) {
            $request['photo'] = $this->uploadImage($photo, $request->name, 'profile');
        }

        $request['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);

        User::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('user.index');
    }
    ...
}
```

**Screenshot Error**
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC17v.png)

Comment: you can add `unique` for field, ex `email`

Comment: @Xupitan Is it like this ? `'email' => 'unique|required|max:255',`

Comment: problem solved `'email' => 'required|max:255|unique:users'`

Comment: yes, it is. You can use same as @Stefano Christian Wiryana answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. First is to add 'unique' to your validation. For example:

```
$validateData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255|',
        'email' => 'required|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|max:255',
        'is_admin' => 'required',
 ]);
```

or you can manually check if the user already exists by adding an if statement like this:

```
if (!User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->get()->isEmpty()) {
        // user with that email already exists
}
```

Reference for the first example: [Laravel unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 0):

On validation rules, add the unique property like this:

```
'email' => 'unique|required|max:255',
```

And show in the blade view; there are two options, the first one is custom for each field:

```
@error('email')
    <span>{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```

And the second is as the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors):

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I also recommended read [Laravel docs validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control this is , check data duplication in validations like so :

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email' // we are checking is it unique on  users table , on email column
```

And showing error in front you can use for specific field :

```
@error
   {{ $message }} // show you error message
@enderror
```

And showing them all together we should do like so :

```
@if($error->any()) 
   // Of course you should if there is , you should loop 
   //over them and something about them .
@endif
```

And for the last thing you can customize you error message by creating request validation and message method . For more information check this link below :
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages